# Covariant differentials and exterior derivative

Tags: differential-geometry

I'm reading S.S. Chern's article *On the minimal immersions of the two-sphere in a space of constant curvature*, published in 1970. In this article, he derived the formula (15) by covariant differential. I compute that $$D^2x=D\left(\sum_{i}\omega_i e_i\right)=\sum_{i}(D\omega_i)e_i+\sum_{i}\omega_iDe_i$$But this article claimed that $$D^2x=\sum_{i}(d\omega_i)e_i+\sum_{i}\omega_iDe_i$$I don't know why $D\omega_i=d\omega_i.$ Maybe my comprehension is wrong and what is true?

Comment: This actually never appears per se in Chern’s paper. He is using $D^2$ for the symmetric second fundamental form. You need the connection  to covariantly differentiate the vector fields $e_i$.  He never claimed $D\omega_i$ should be $d\omega_i$, insofar as he is finding a symmetric $2$-tensor, not a $2$-form.  But, as I said, he never wrote what you claimed. He looks only at the terms orthogonal to the submanifold. (By the way, you should make your questions self-contained. I just happen to have Chern’s complete works.)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I will make my question self-contained for the next time. But I still don't know how to derive $D^2 x$ from (3), (10) and (14). Can you give me some hints or a full solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that Chern is very careful with his ranges of indices with different letter ranges. We have $1\le i,j\le n$,  $\ n+1\le \alpha,\beta\le N$, and $1\le A,B\le N$.

We have $De_A = \sum \omega_{AB}\otimes e_B$. Since $\{\omega_A\}$ and $\{e_B\}$ are dual bases, you can check that $D\omega_A = \sum\omega_{AB}\otimes\omega_B$ [but Chern never uses this]. Therefore, we start with $Dx = \sum\omega_i\otimes e_i$, and so
\begin{align*}
D^2x &= \sum \omega_i\otimes De_i + D\omega_i\otimes e_i = \sum\omega_i\otimes \omega_{iA}\otimes e_A + \omega_{iA}\otimes\omega_A\otimes e_i\\ &= \sum (\omega_i\otimes\omega_{ij} - \omega_{ij}\otimes\omega_i)\otimes e_j + \sum (\omega_i\otimes\omega_{i\alpha})\otimes e_\alpha.
\end{align*}

All Chern cares about is the second fundamental form, i.e., the terms orthogonal to the submanifold, and that is the second term in that sum. (The tangential terms, because we're working with the torsion-free connection, recover the exterior derivative.)

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. However, I still don't know how to prove that $$D\omega_{A}=\sum\omega_{BA}\otimes\omega_{B}.$$Here is my naive try. $$(D\omega_A)(e_C, e_D)=(D_{e_C}\omega_A)(e_C)=-\omega_A(D_{e_C}e_D)=-\omega_{DA}(e_C)$$On the other hand $$(\sum\omega_{BA}\otimes\omega_{B})(e_C,e_D)=\omega_{DA}(e_C)$$ It must be somewhere wrong.

Comment: I would just differentiate $\omega_A(e_B)=\delta_{AB}$. Then $0=D\omega_a(e_B)+\omega_A(De_B) = D\omega_A(e_B) + \omega_{BA}$, so $D\omega_A = -\sum\omega_{BA}\otimes\omega_B = \sum\omega_{AB}\otimes\omega_B$. You're right that I had a sign error in my formula. My apologies. I have edited.